# Define Custom Log Level in Configuration file and Access them is Java Code, Log4J2

Tags: java, log4j2

I would like to define custom log levels in configurations file like below

```
<CustomLevels>
    <CustomLevel name="DIAG" intLevel="350" />
    <CustomLevel name="NOTICE" intLevel="450" />
    <CustomLevel name="VERBOSE" intLevel="550" />
</CustomLevels>
```

And i want to access them in Java Code like

```
Level diag = // get level defined in configuration
// and use them like this
logger.log(diag, "message");
// and then this 'message' is printed in the appender with thresholdfilter as diag
```

And then put a threshold filter on appender comparing with the level defined in configurations file...

Is this possible? And if yes, then how?

Answer (score 1):

Define custom levels like this:

```
public static final Level DIAG = Level.forName("DIAG", 350)
```

So all you need is to read those levels in from the configurations file (on startup) and assigned them to some static variables.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```
logger.log(Level.getLevel("DIAG"), "your message");
```

As stated in [the log4j2 doc](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customloglevels.html)